# How can I make my bot commands only run on servers and not on private messages?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

What happens is that if I send a command like the avatar command or some moderation command to the bot via private message, it causes an error because it doesn't get the properties it requires.

I am using discord js v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### v13

Use discord.js's [`message.inGuild()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=inGuild) method.

```js
if (!message.inGuild()) return;
```

or for an error message:

```js
if (!message.inGuild()) return message.channel.send("Use this command in a guild!");
```

#### v12

Use the [`message.channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type) property.

```js
if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
```

or for an error message:

```js
if (message.channel.type === "dm") return message.channel.send("Use this command in a guild!");
```